# Visually differentiating arguments of If

Tags: code-organization

Is there a convention for writing `If` expressions to visually differentiate between the different arguments? For example:

```
If[conditional,
    expr1;
    expr2;
    expr3,
    expr4;
    expr5
]
```

In this code, it is very difficult at a glance to notice that the `,` after `expr3` marks the separation between the true and false parts of the expression. Using *Extend Selection* works, but can only highlight one full potion at a times, making examining nested statements cumbersome. A potential solution would be to abstract the expressions into multiple functions, but when the code is only a few lines long this seems like overkill. Wrapping each argument in a singe function, like

```
If[conditional,
    Module[{},
        expr1;
        expr2;
        expr3
    ],
    Module[{},
        expr4;
        expr5
    ]
]
```

works somewhat, but does increase indentation, which is annoying for nested expressions

Is there a better solution, or should I just pick something and stick with it?

Comment: I wonder is there a clean want to change the symbols? Especially on my linux system the semicolon and comma are very hard to distinguish.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Several users place commas in the beginning of lines instead of at the end, which makes it a little bit easier to differentiate when a new argument begins. Here are two more styles that you may consider:

```
If[(
  expr1;
  expr2;
  expr3
  )
 ,
 (
  expr3;
  expr4;
  expr5
  )
 ]
```

And

```
If[
 CompoundExpression[
  expr1
  , expr2
  , expr3
  ],
 CompoundExpression[
  expr4
  , expr5
  , expr6
  ]
 ]
```

Eschewing shorthand notation such as `;` for the proper name of the function is useful in many scenarios. When my code looks hard to read I often try to replace `/@` with `Map` and so on.

Comment: +1, I also use a comma on a separate line (as in your first example), to more clearly delimit arguments of "functions" like `If`, `While`, `Switch`, etc.

Answer (score 5):

```
 If[conditional (*then*),
     expr1;
     expr2;
     expr3
   (*else*),
     expr4;
     expr5
  (*endif*) ]
```